# Using wget, how to download to a specific location, without creating folders, and always overwrite original files

Tags: files, terminal, wget

How do I use `wget` to download files to a specific location, without creating directories, and overwrite the original every time.

I've tried using the `-r` `-P` and `nc` options in combination but this resulted in several undesirable effects.

```
wget -P ./temp -r "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/master/README.md" -nd
```

The above downloads `README.md` to the `/temp` directory in the current folder, but preserves the original `README.md` and numbers all subsequent `README.md` files.

```
wget -r -P ./temp "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/master/README.md" -nd
```

Above command does the same thing.

```
wget -P ./temp -nc "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/master/README.md" -r
```

With this one, the file is replaced but directories are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the required result in `wget` (or `curl`) by specifying an output document.

With `wget`:

```
wget https://raw.git...etc.../README.md -O ./temp/README.md
```

With `curl`:

```
curl https://raw.git...etc.../master/README.md > ./temp/README.md
```

Comment: This answer does not match the question's criteria:
download to a specified location, download files without creating directories, and overwrite the original files every time.

Comment: The question specifies the file must be overwritten each time and no folders must be created.. Specifying the original file as output each time achieves this. How does the above not match your requirements?

Comment: Sorry, I misread something, they work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Saving file content to output file won't work with binary files.

I observed that only files that contains extension (have . in their name) are downloaded in a new folder with the same name:

For example, wget 2 files: `my_archive.zip` and `no_extension_file` 
using commands:

```
    wget -P ~/Downloads/no_extension_file https://<IP>/no_extension_file
    wget -p ~/Downloads/my_archive.zip https://<IP>/my_archive.zip
```

will result in:

```
   ~/Downloads/no_extension_file
   ~/Downloads/my_archive.zip/my_archive.zip
```